# Why Do People Feel "Safe & Secure" with Their Emotional Distress?

Tags: emotion

I have noticed in some of my family members, who've been through struggles in life, to extremely "cling" into their sad emotions! They **don't **want**** let go of it. It almost feels like they feel safe and secure with their emotional "miseries". I have searched the net and found this is a common phenomena in many people. I was wondering if there is any scientific paper written on this subject. I don't know the proper terminology for this behavior. I was hoping someone can shed some light. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are right, and consolation often backfires. this is for 2 reasons.

1. We as human beings, want to be witnessed, heared. Few year ago a video based on research work of Megan Devine went viral over internet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2zLCCRT-nE
https://refugeingrief.com/

2. Lot of positivity we say, is actually "toxic positivity". It make our pain invalidated, disbelieved, or may have a discriminatory "bad vibes unwelcome" approach. Toxic positivity may oppress people from telling their problem and finding a solution.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-man-cave/201908/toxic-positivity-dont-always-look-the-bright-side